# android sqlite: getting wrong values

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently I got a lot of troubles in android with sqlite databases. This time, it's really weird.

Everytime I enter a certain Activity, I want to display the latest three entries, like "team 1 vs. team 2 goals - goals". Bizarrely, the database is returning wrong values. Let's start with the current database content:

[image]

important for my question here are columns "id", "goals1" and "goals2". Now as you see, the latest three games are "4: dfsadf vs. asf 3-2", "3: df vs. as 3-2" and "2: dfa vs. dfas 2-0". In my Activity, following is displaid:

[image]

As you see, the goals of the away team goals are wrong (and it seems the entry's ID is set as away goals).
I set the text of these three buttons like this:

```
entries = datasource.getLatestFootballEntry(challengeName);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_overview_latest1);
            entry = entries.elementAt(0);
            buttonText = entry.date + ": " + entry.team1 + " vs. " + entry.team2 + " " + entry.goals1 + "-" + entry.goals2;
            button.setText(buttonText);
            button.setClickable(true);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_overview_latest2);
            entry = entries.elementAt(1);
            buttonText = entry.date + ": " + entry.team1 + " vs. " + entry.team2 + " " + entry.goals1 + "-" + entry.goals2;
            button.setText(buttonText);
            button.setClickable(true);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_overview_latest3);
            entry = entries.elementAt(2);
            buttonText = entry.date + ": " + entry.team1 + " vs. " + entry.team2 + " " + entry.goals1 + "-" + entry.goals2;
            button.setText(buttonText);
            button.setClickable(true);
```

Here I get the specific entries:

```
public Vector<FootballEntry> getLatestFootballEntry(String challengeName){
        Vector<FootballEntry> entries = new Vector<FootballEntry>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(CustomSQLiteHelper.TABLE_FOOTBALL, allColumns2, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToLast();
        int i=0;
        while(i<3 && !cursor.isBeforeFirst()){
            if(checkIfCorrectChallengeName(cursor, challengeName)){
                entries.add(cursorToFootballEntry(cursor));
                i++;
            }
            cursor.moveToPrevious();
        }
        return entries;
    }
```

Now the strange part comes. When I do following changes in the method where I set the text on buttons, everything is fine.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_overview_latest1);
            datasource.open();
            entry = datasource.getSpecificFootballEntry(entries.elementAt(0).id);
            datasource.close();
            buttonText = entry.date + ": " + entry.team1 + " vs. " + entry.team2 + " " + entry.goals1 + "-" + entry.goals2;
            button.setText(buttonText);
            button.setClickable(true);
```

now displaid

[image]

This is my cursorToFootballEntry method

```
private FootballEntry cursorToFootballEntry(Cursor cursor){
    FootballEntry entry = new FootballEntry();
    entry.id = cursor.getLong(0);
    entry.challengeName = cursor.getString(1);
    entry.date = cursor.getString(2);
    entry.home = cursor.getInt(3);
    entry.platform = cursor.getString(4);
    entry.team1 = cursor.getString(5);
    entry.stars1 = cursor.getDouble(6);
    entry.team2 = cursor.getString(7);
    entry.stars2 = cursor.getDouble(8);
    entry.goals1 = cursor.getInt(9);
    Log.i("dfasdf", "IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  " + cursor.getInt(9) + "-" + cursor.getInt(10) + "   id: " + cursor.getLong(0));
    entry.goals2 = cursor.getInt(10);
    entry.finished = cursor.getInt(11);
    return entry;
}
```

As you see, I print some infos into the log (namely the two values of the team's goals). The Output is

```
09-29 22:50:18.191: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  3-4   id: 4
09-29 22:50:18.191: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  3-3   id: 3
09-29 22:50:18.201: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  2-2   id: 2
09-29 22:50:18.241: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  3-2   id: 4
```

So basically, the entry with ID 4 is read out two times, but there are two different away goal values. What can cause this? I mean, it's no difference whether I get 3 games at once or three times a single game, as long they are the same games, what obviously must be (seeing the id's). Getting a single game returns always the right values. The same thing happens, if I get all games (needed in a different Activity). In the database creation declaration, there is only one value set to "autoincrement", and thast the _id, nothing else.

Now to "prove" this, I entered a new entry, score 1-0: following is displaid (with the second variant of setting the text, means the first will be correct)

[image]

Log

```
09-29 23:02:13.281: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  1-5   id: 5
09-29 23:02:13.291: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  3-4   id: 4
09-29 23:02:13.291: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  3-3   id: 3
09-29 23:02:13.311: I/dfasdf(7039): IN CURSOR TO FOOENRTY  1-0   id: 5
```

**EDIT**: of course a solution would be to get only the ID's of the latest games, and the get them seperately, but the motivation of my question is more to understand why this can happen.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Since I'm very new to databases, which query exactly do you mean? As I understand it by now, by working with extension of SQLiteOpenHelper, with querys I put the cursor to a specific position (and then I'm moving it "by hand", like "moveToNext() as long xy").

Comment: can you post the queries, like the part when you do the SELECT or the likes (whichever did you use, contentresolver or wat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving backwards through the cursor does not seem to work.

However, there is no guarantee that records are returned in any particular order if you don't explicitly specify an ordering, so it would be altogether easier to modify the query so that it returns exactly the records you want:

```
cursor = database.query(CustomSQLiteHelper.TABLE_FOOTBALL,
                        allColumns2,
                        null, null,
                        null, null,
                        "id DESC",  // return largest id values first
                        "3");       // return no more than 3 records
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    ...
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid LIMIT clauses: LIMIT 3

Comment: Edited; the `LIMIT` is automatically inserted by `query()`.

Comment: How to specify skip in the above syntax

Comment: @kishore Not at all; use `rawQuery`.

Comment: @CL hey no need of raw query i specified 3,2 and it worked where 3 is skip value and 2 is limit value.

Comment: @kishore AFAIK some Android versions accept only a single number there.